# How do I return multiple datatables from a SQL Server stored procedured?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to make two queries on two different tables and the data isn't really related. So when I call the stored proc through my code, I should be getting a DataSet with two DataTables, one DataTable for each query. How is that done in SQL Server stored procs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply execute two SELECT statements in the proc:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
SELECT * FROM Bla
```

when you then Fill() a dataset, you'll get two datatables, one with the first resultset, the other with the second.

Comment: you may want to specify the columns for performance purposes. Like, select column1, column2, etc...

Comment: I know. It was just an example.

Comment: Make sure to add SET NOCOUNT ON or your client will see the 'x rows effected' as another resultset.